# StanfordNLP Openie fails

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have StanfordNLP up and running.

My maven dependency structure is as follows:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

My code runs just fine as follows:

```
@Test
public void testTA() throws Exception
{

    Path p = Paths.get("s.txt");

    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(p);
    String s = new String(encoded);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, ner, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // read some text in the text variable
    String text = s;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append(text);
    sb.append(
            "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n===================================================================\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    // these are all the sentences in this document
    // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and
    // has values with custom types
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    sb.append(
            "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n+++++++++++++++++++++++SENTENCES++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
    {
        // traversing the words in the current sentence
        // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
        sb.append("\n\n\n==============SENTENCE==============\n\n\n");
        sb.append(sentence.toString());
        sb.append("\n");
        for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
        {
            // this is the text of the token
            sb.append("\n==============TOKEN==============\n");
            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
            sb.append(word);
            sb.append(" : ");
            // this is the POS tag of the token
            String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
            // this is the NER label of the token
            sb.append(pos);
            sb.append(" : ");
            String lemma = token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class);
            sb.append(lemma);
            sb.append(" : ");
            String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
            sb.append(ne);
            sb.append("\n");

        }

        // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
        Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
        sb.append("\n\n\n=====================TREE==================\n\n\n");
        sb.append(tree.toString());

        // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
        SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
        sb.append("\n\n\n");
        sb.append(dependencies.toString());
    }
```

However, when I add openie to the pipeline, the code fails.

props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, ner, dcoref, openie");

The error I get is as follows:

annotator "openie" requires annotator "natlog"

Can anyone advise me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that annotators in the pipeline can depend on each other. 
Simply add natlog to the pipeline.
Crucially, dependencies must be added first, so

- natlog must be in the pipeline before openie.
- depparse must be in the pipeline before natlog

and as an aside,

- parse must be in the pipeline before dcoref.

Comment: In the GitHub code (i.e., versions of CoreNLP after 3.6.0), you can actually get away with not adding depparse before natlog if you already have the parse annotator. But for now, yes -- you need to add `depparse,natlog` somewhere between `lemma` and `openie` in the annotators list.

Comment: Thanks, Also, thanks to everyone who is supporting standfordNLP on SO. Really helpful!

Comment: @Gabor, if you or a colleague could look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803277/stanford-ner-abstractsequenceclassifier-vs-namedentitytagannotation
Wouldn't ask if I didn't think it would help the community.